# toHaveBeenCalledWith() error: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular11

In Component **.ts** file

```
onScrollToProductSelector(){
   let offset = document.getElementById("selector").offsetTop;
   window.scrollBy({
      top: offset,
      behavior: "smooth"
   });
}
```

In **.spec.ts** file

```
it("should call window.scrollby", () => {
        spyOn<any>(window, "scrollBy");
        let topOffset = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#selector").offsetTop;
        const mockObj = {
            top: topOffset,
            behavior: "smooth"
        }
        component.onScrollToProductSelector();
        expect(window.scrollBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockObj);
});
```

But when I run this test case, I am getting following error:

> error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: at which line it shows the error?

Comment: @AakashGarg this line
`expect(window.scrollBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockObj);`

Comment: try changing expect(window.scrollBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockObj) to expect(window.scrollBy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockObj, undefined). if it works let me know and i will put it as answer.

Comment: @aakashgarg it didn't work. Now it is giving another error to first argument saying : Argument of type {top: number, behavior:string} is not assignable to parameter of type number | asymetricMatcher<any>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @uminder suggested [#42455](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/42455),

window.scrollBy is an overloaded method and default it is considering the 2 argument overloaded method.
`window.scrollBy(x, y);`

**Solution is:** instead of checking that method is called with ... arguments, **checking for the 1st argument to be the ... argument object.**

```
it("should call window.scrollby", () => {
        let spyCall = spyOn<any>(window, "scrollBy");
        let topOffset = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#selector").offsetTop;
        const mockObj = {
            top: topOffset,
            behavior: "smooth"
        }
        component.onScrollToProductSelector();
        expect(spyCall.calls.argsFor(0)).toEqual([mockObj]);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem is due to `DefinitelyTyped` issue [#42455](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/42455).

[`Window.scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) is an overloaded method.

```
window.scrollBy(x-coord, y-coord);
window.scrollBy(options)
```

You're using the version `window.scrollBy(options)` in your code but `toHaveBeenCalledWith` tries to find a match for `window.scrollBy(x-coord, y-coord)`.

There are apparently ways to solve this problem. Carefully read the comments within the `DefinitelyTyped` issue [#42455](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/42455) and choose the one that best suits you.

Comment: Thanks, @uminder this solution has worked.